# .setHours return wrong hours

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, momentjs

I'm using `FullCalendar 2.3.1` with `moment js 2.9.0`, actually I get the date in this way:

```
var currDateStart = $calendar.fullCalendar('getView').start;
```

this return me:

> Mon Oct 26 2015 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (ora solare Europa occidentale)

NB: the date above is a `moment object`

So in the next step I want convert the date in ISO format:

```
currDateStart =  new Date(new Date(currDateStart).setHours(0)).toISOString();
```

and I get this:

> 2015-10-25T23:00:00.000Z

But the result is incorrect 'cause should be:

> 2015-10-25T00:00:00.000Z

The wrong date bug my calendar rendering event. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you think it should be midnight?  You've got 1am on the 26th in a timezone +1.  You then set the hours to 0, giving you midnight on the 26th in a timezone +1.  You then want the ISO time, which is without the timezone info, giving you 25th at 11pm.  Also should your expected result be the 26th - is that a typo?

Comment: The start date of the event is that I returned late Sunday and Monday, as I fix returning Monday midnight?

Comment: I did not understand, I have to first convert the date and then set the ISO format? Can you show me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is correct, and as expected. ISOString is returning a date in UTC. Notice the Z at end of `2015-10-25T23:00:00.000Z`.

You are in a timezone of +1 UTC, so when you set `setHours(0)` - It sets the time in your zone, and ISOString gets back in UTC (which is 1 hour behind). You can `setHours(1)` to counter for this, or tweak the function that uses the output to expect a date in UTC (local time - 1hr).

Answer (score 0):

Here what happent is when i try to set hours to date it will convert date into GMT+0530 and then it will convert date to ISO string

```js
var currDateStarttemp = 'Mon Oct 26 2015 1:00:00 GMT+0100 (ora solare Europa occidentale)';

var currDateStart = new Date(currDateStarttemp).toISOString();
snippet.log("currDateStart " + currDateStart);
currDateStart = new Date(currDateStart).setUTCHours(0)
snippet.log("setHours " + new Date(currDateStart));
currDateStart = new Date(currDateStart).toISOString();
snippet.log("toISOString " + currDateStart);
```

```html
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: The problem's that the final date that I want get should be: 2015-10-26T00:00:00.000ZZ how I can achieve this?

Comment: i have updated my code. i think this will solve your issue